# FTP Using Bash on Linux Centos 6

Tags: bash, ftp

I have been trying to make bash program for ftp to another server, my problem is when i execute my file.sh it says "530 Login authentication failed"
but i wrote correct username, host and password. 
when i try to do FTP using PHP and it is done well.

Comment: Please post your file.sh.

Comment: And your PHP file.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
HOST='---.---.---.---'
USER='------'
PASSWD='-------'

ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER 
$PASSWD
prompt
cd upload
ls -la
bye
EOT

Comment: @galihutama Edit your post ant insert this there